# how to insert hex value inside an hex char array

Tags: c++, winapi, binary, hex

I have a loop let say from 1 to 32. 1 to 32 are decimal in this case.  I have to insert the hex value of 1 to 32 in an unsigned char array and then perform send. My code looks like this

```
char hex[3];
unsigned char hexunsigned[3];
int dec; 
int i=0;
do
{
    // this is the unsigned char array , i have to insert at 4th pos.  
   unsigned char writebuffer[8] ={0x01, 0x05, 0x00, 0x20, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};

   // to place the hex value of each point on writeBuffer[3]
   dec=i+1;
   decimal_hex(dec,hex); //this function returns hex value of corresponding i value.
   memcpy(hexunsigned,hex,sizeof(hexunsigned)); //converting char to unsigned char

   writebuffer[3]= hexunsigned; //shows the error cannot convert from 'unsigned char [3]' to 'unsigned char'

   unsigned short int crc = CRC16(writebuffer, 6); // Calculates the CRC16 of all 8 bytes
   writebuffer[6] = ((unsigned char*) &crc)[1];
   writebuffer[7] = ((unsigned char*) &crc)[0];

   serialObj.send(writebuffer, 8);
   //send another packet only after getting the response
   DWORD nBytesRead = serialObj.Read(inBuffer, sizeof(inBuffer));
   i++;

}while(nBytesRead!=0 && i<32);
```

so, the line

```
writebuffer[3]= hexunsigned;
```

shows the error as cannot convert from `'unsigned char [3]'` to `'unsigned char'`. 
how to insert `hex unsigned` in `writebuffer` array.

when

```
char hex[3];
int dec;
dec=i+1;
decimal_hex(dec,hex); 
memcpy(writebuffer+3, hex, sizeof(writebuffer+3));
```

is used , it is translating 01(dec) as 31.

I have tried the below code also , it is also translating  01(dec) as 31.

```
sprintf(hex, "%X", dec); 
memcpy(writebuffer+3, hex, sizeof(writebuffer+3));
```

I think it is treating '1' received at hex variable as ascii and sending hex value of character '1' as 31.

The send function is below:

```
void serial::send(unsigned char data[], DWORD noOfByte)
{
    DWORD dwBytesWrite;
    WriteFile(serialHandle, data, noOfByte, &dwBytesWrite, NULL);
}
```

Comment: What type is `hexunsigned`?

Answer (score 1):

You can merge the two lines

```
memcpy(hexunsigned,hex,sizeof(hexunsigned)); //converting char to unsigned char

writebuffer[3]= hexunsigned;
```

into one:

```
memcpy(writebuffer+3, hex, 3);</strike>
```

and the temporary hexunsigned is redundant
***--------------------Update line--------------------***
Actually when we say hex encoding, we want to use two bytes to represent an original byte, for example 
    `0x33 30 // '3' '0'` represents     `0x30`
So in you case `0x01~0x20` should be represented as `0x00 01` to `0x02 00`, if you want to use sprintf to convert from dec to hex, you can use as this:

```
sprintf(hex, "%02X", dec); 
memcpy(writebuffer+3, hex, 2);
```

And your output will be like this `"01 05 00 30 31 00 00 00"` for i=1 without CRC16 considered.

Comment: using above memcpy it is sending  "01 05 00 31 00 cc 9c 50" for i =1; it is converting 1 as 31 . and other i=2 is converted as 32. for i =1 it should be 01 not 31. how to do correct conversion

Comment: is "01 05 00 01 00 cc 9c 50" the expected output for i=1? and what is the expected output for i = 12?

Comment: yea my expected output is "01 05 00 01 00 cc 9c 50" for i = 12, my expected output is 01 02 00 0C 00 CC 9C 50. . My code is treating 12 as character and sending its hex value..:(

Comment: If so, it is definitely not hex, you can simply use  `writebuffer[3]=dec`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use memcpy to copy a three char array.

Answer (score 0):

hexunsigned must be a unsigned char array, and writebuffer[3] is a unsigned char.

You can not assign a unsigned char to a unsigned char array.

If you want to copy hexunsigned to writebuffer[3] address, use memcpy.

Comment: decimal value 01 is converted as 31 instead of 01. What can be the cause

Comment: `sprintf(hex, "%X", 1)` will assign hex='1' (attention, it's a character '1' not a number 1), after this if you use `printf("%X",hex[0])` you will see 31.